# Tying additional data to each value of an enum

Tags: java, enums

As we all know it is impossible to extend an enum, for very good reasons. However I have run into a case where I need to add some additional information to each value of an already implemented enum that comes from a separate library, this library is in my control but should not contain information specific to the application I am developing at the moment.

### Example

Let's say I use a library that provides a day of week enum like so:

```
public enum DayOfWeek {
    MONDAY,
    TUESDAY,
    WEDNESDAY,
    THURSDAY,
    FRIDAY,
    SATURDAY,
    SUNDAY;
}
```

Other classes in this external library use this `enum` extensively.

Now let's say that we are writing a appointment scheduling application, so we want to somehow tie a closing time to each value of `DayOfWeek`, if `DayOfWeek` was a part of our application we could just a add a field and a constructor to it but that is not an option here.

### Important considerations

1. Whatever solution we pick should act as much as possible like an instance of `DayOfWeek`. Preferably I should be able to pass around an object which can be used as a `DayOfWeek` but that also contains a closing time.
2. Missing value detection. If a value is added to or removed from `DayOfWeek` (maybe aliens with an 8 day week invaded or something) then our implementation should fail as early as possible until a corresponding closing time is added to our library. Preferably at compile time.
3. Ease of use. It should be obvious how to get a closing time from a `DayOfWeek` for a new developer of our application.
4. Maintainability. It should be as difficult as possible to mess up making changes to our implementation.
5. Ease of development. This is the least important but a good solution shouldn't be too difficult to implement.

### What I have tried

My initial thoughts on this was a simple switch statement in a helper method Like as follows:

```
public static String getClosingTime(DayOfWeek day) {
    switch (day) {
    case MONDAY:
    case TUESDAY:
    case WEDNESDAY:
    case THURSDAY:
        return "17:30";
    case FRIDAY:
        return "16:00";
    case SATURDAY:
    case SUNDAY:
        return "Closed";
    default:
        return null;
    }
}
```

(Return values are `String`'s for simplicity, they should obviously be some kind of object in a real world case).

This succeeds on point 3 to 5 but is burdensome to use as this method has to be called every time a closing time is needed.

Comment: Do you really have to use this enum from that library? It seems to be you'd be much better off implementing your own enum and adding all the required methods there.

Comment: @lexicore The class has to be used somewhere as it is required for interactions with the library but it can definitely be wrapped or otherwise hidden away. Your answer with an added interface is a nice way to do this

Comment: You can easily add `MyDayOfWeek.asDayOfWeek()` to your own enum `MyDayOfWeek`. I think your own enum `MyDayOfWeek` with the switch-trick as @RobertKock suggested would be the best solution. A visitor pattern like in my answer is good for the case you want to completely separate application-special logic from the enum. If you're OK with bringing all the special things in your own enum, then it's the way to go.

Comment: @lexicore Ah sorry, I'm reading this on my phone and got the two answers mixed up. Your answer is really good too, just not quite right for my use case. I wish I could accept both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have to use `DayOfWeek` directly I would prefer an interface (in the same `package` as your `enum DayOfWeek`) like

```
public interface IDayOfWeek {

    DayOfWeek getDayOfWeek();
}
```

and edit your `enum` to

```
public enum DayOfWeek implements IDayOfWeek {
    MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY;

    @Override
    public DayOfWeek getDayOfWeek() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Now you're able to craete a new `enum` like

```
public enum DayOfWeekAndClosingTime implements IDayOfWeek {
    MONDAY(DayOfWeek.MONDAY, "17:30"),
    TUESDAY(DayOfWeek.TUESDAY, "17:30"),
    WEDNESDAY(DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY, "17:30"),
    THURSDAY(DayOfWeek.THURSDAY, "17:30"),
    FRIDAY(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY, "16:00"),
    SATURDAY(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY, "Closed"),
    SUNDAY(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY, "Closed");

    private final DayOfWeek day;
    private final String closingTime;

    DayOfWeekAndClosingTime(DayOfWeek day, String closingTime) {
        this.day = day;
        this.closingTime = closingTime;
    }

    @Override
    public DayOfWeek getDayOfWeek() {
        return day;
    }

    public String getClosingTime() {
        return closingTime;
    }
}
```

Now you can treat your additional information as a day of week:

```
public void handleDayOfWeek(IDayOfWeek day) {
    DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = day.getDayOfWeek();
    // do something
    if (day instanceof DayOfWeekAndClosingTime)
        handleClosingTime((DayOfWeekAndClosingTime) day);
}
```

The negative point is the cross reference between `DayOfWeek` and `IDayOfWeek`

EDIT: to check added values in `DayOfWeek` you can add a static block

```
static {
    if (DayOfWeekAndClosingTime.values().length != DayOfWeek.values().length)
        throw new IllegalStateException("missing closing times");
}
```

There you could also check if all `day`s of your wrapping `enum` are disjunct.

EDIT 2: Thanks to RobertKock

To get a compiler warning you can reduce the constructor by the `String` parameter and change it to

```
DayOfWeekAndClosingTime(DayOfWeek day) {
    this.day = day;
    String time = "unknown";
    switch(day) {
        case MONDAY:
        case TUESDAY:
        case WEDNESDAY:
        case THURSDAY:
            time = "17:30";
            break;
        case FRIDAY:
            time = "16:00";
            break;
        case SATURDAY:
        case SUNDAY:
            time = "closed";
            break;
    }
    this.closingTime = time;
}
```

Comment: Imagine a new day of week will be added. How would you notice this?

Comment: I don't know a solution to get it at compile time. But I added a runtime solution to my answer

Comment: Within the constructor of DayOfWeekAndClosingTime you could add a switch over the passed day without a default. The compiler gives a warning if not all cases are covered.

Comment: @RobertKock Excellent idea.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little bit crazy idea. You can extend your enum to accept a visitor.

```
public interface DayOfWeekVisitor<R> {
    public R onMonday();
    public R onTuesday();
    // ...
}

public enum DayOfWeek {
    MONDAY {
        public <R> R accept(DayOfWeekVisitor<R> visitor) { return visitor.onMonday(); }
    },
    // ...
    ;
    public <R> R accept(DayOfWeekVisitor<R> visitor);
}
```

Then for all of your `DayOfWeek`-dependent operations you'll implement specific visitors:

```
public class ClosingTimeVisitor extends DayOfWeekVisitor<String> {
    public String onMonday() { return "17:30"; }
    // ...
}
```

Yes, this extends the enum - but not with any application-specific things.

How does it fit your requirements?

1. I think `dayOfWeek.visit(ClosingTimeVisitor.INSTANCE)` is, well, OK. Not brilliant but fine.
2. Missing value detection. If we (hopefully) get invaded by aliens who also have Bumbsday, you'll add `onBumbsday` to your `DayOfWeekVisitor` interface. This will immediately force you - per compiler error - to implement this method in all the `DayOfWeekVisitor` implementations you have.
3. Ease of use. `dayOfWeek.visit(ClosingTimeVisitor.INSTANCE)` or even with some syntactic sugar `dayOfWeek.calculate(CLOSING_TIME)` seems quite easy for me. Not the usual thing for starters but I think it's quite easy to understand the concept.
4. Maintainability. It's a bit har to evaluate this. But I think it will be fine. At least better than maintaining mappings with `Map<DayOfWeek, String>` and likes.
5. Ease of development. Seems pretty easy to me.

Answer (score 0):

For these cases, we follow the following implementation.

```
public enum DayOfWeek {

    MONDAY(null),
    TUESDAY(null),
    WEDNESDAY(null),
    THURSDAY("17:30"),
    FRIDAY("16:00"),
    SATURDAY(null),
    SUNDAY("Closed");


    private String closingTime;
    public String getClosingTime() {
        return closingTime;
    }


    private DayOfWeek(String closingTime) {
        this.closingTime = closingTime;
    }
}
```

Here's how to access it.

```
DayOfWeek.SUNDAY.getClosingTime(); // it returns "Closed"
```

Comment: I think this breaks "enum that comes from a separate library, this library is in my control but *should not contain information specific to the application I am developing at the moment*".

Comment: Yes, I would love to do this but as mentioned in the question it is not an option.

Comment: @lexicore Oh! totally missed the point that the enum belongs to an external library and should not contain app specific info.